# Pass a list as argument with argparse

Tags: python, bash, list, argparse

Is it possible to pass a list variable as an argument to the argparse module?

It has been seen to use `nargs` option

```
parser.add_argument('--my_arg', --nargs='+', type=int)
```

and pass some values as:

```
python script.py --my_arg 2 6 9
```

Instead, is it possible to do the following?

```
my_list=[2,6,9]

python script.py --my_arg my_list
```

Comment: This seems to be more a shell question than a Python question. Do you understand what the shell *is*, and how arguments are passed to programs, including Python scripts? What shell are you using, and on which operating system?

Comment: Not sure if it's a shell question but feel free to provide some insight. I'm using bash on Ubuntu.

Comment: What does `python`'s `argparse` have to do with shell option processing; i.e. why the `bash` tag?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the operating system and shell used. For example, if you are  on a unix-like system and using zsh, you could do

```
my_list=(2 6 9)
python script.py --my_arg $my_list
```

Zsh is quite forgiving here as it will expand entire arrays if you omit the index and, unlike most shells, it won't split elements of `my_list` into separate words if there are spaces in them. In Bash, I *think* you have to do something like this

```
my_list=(1 2 "hello there")
python script.py --my_arg "${my_list[@]}"
```

Chech the [bash manual on arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays) for details.

Comment: You don't need `declare -a` for zsh, only bash requires that

Comment: @smac89 You don't need to declare plain arrays in bash, either, just assign to them with parentheses after the `=` (i.e. `var=value` creates a plain variable, `var=(value)` creates an array). You *do* need to declare associative (i.e. string-indexed arrays).

Comment: BTW, the correct syntax to expand all elements of an array in bash (or ksh) requires braces as well: `"${my_list[@]}"`

Comment: Thanks to GordonDavisson and smac89 for the corrections; I have edited them into the code!